# Troubles with reading JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, file

I can't read json file in js. I tryed the code bellow, but I've got an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

```
    <script>
    function loadJSON(callback) {   
      var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
      xobj.open('GET', 'weather.json', true);
      xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
          callback(JSON.parse(xobj.responseText));
        }
      };
    }

    //usage:
    loadJSON(function(json) {
      console.log(json); 
    });
    </script>
```

My json file contains such data:

```
{
   "RegionPK{region='kirovohrad', observation=6, forecast=12, level=100000.0}":{
      "temperatureStatistics":{
         "count":26,
         "sum":123.400146484375,
         "min":3.850006103515625,
         "max":6.75,
         "average":4.746159480168269
      },
      "humidityStatistics":{
         "count":26,
         "sum":1797.7999954223633,
         "min":56.599998474121094,
         "max":79.4000015258789,
         "average":69.1461536700909
      },
      "cloudnessStatistics":{
         "count":17,
         "sum":0.0,
         "min":0.0,
         "max":0.0,
         "average":0.0
      }
   },
   "RegionPK{region='dnipropetrovsk', observation=0, forecast=3, level=100000.0}":{
      "temperatureStatistics":{
         "count":46,
         "sum":90.8670654296875,
         "min":1.181884765625,
         "max":2.481903076171875,
         "average":1.975370987601902
      },
      "humidityStatistics":{
         "count":46,
         "sum":3598.199996948242,
         "min":72.0,
         "max":83.30000305175781,
         "average":78.22173906409222
      },
      "cloudnessStatistics":{
         "count":32,
         "sum":0.0,
         "min":0.0,
         "max":0.0,
         "average":0.0
      }
   }
}
```

An error appears here: `RegionPK{region='kirovohrad',observation=6,forecast=12,level=100000.0}":{`
but at the same time my file has passed json validation. So, can I read this file in any way or my 
json file isn't valid?

Comment: Is the excerpt the exact content of `xobj.responseText` before parsing?

Answer (score 0):

The data you have provided is a JSON object, you can't use that with JSON.parse - that should be passed a JSON string which then returns a JSON object.

For the data you have provided, if I call `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonFile))` (where jsonFile is the data you have given above) it returns a correct JSON object, so I don't think there is any problem with the data (as you have provided it).